Expectation of the process adapted to the filtration of the Wiener process
Suppose $\sigma_t$ is a stochastic process adapted to the filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$ generated by the Wiener process $W_t$.
I would like to know how to compute the following expectation:
$$E = \mathbb{E}\left[\exp\{AW_t\}\sigma_t\} \right], \tag{1}$$
were $\sigma(t)$ depends on $W_t$ and $A$ is a constant.
I'm aware of the following result. For random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ and an integrable function $g(x)$ we have:
$$\mathbb{E}[g(X_2)\mathbb{E}[X_1|X_2]] = \mathbb{E}[g(X_2)X_1]. \tag{2}$$
I try to apply this result to my case. I set $X_2 = W_t$, $g(W_t)=\exp\{AW_t\}$ and $X_1 = \sigma_t$. Then
\begin{align}
    E &= \mathbb{E}[\color{red}{g(W_t)}\color{blue}{X_1}] \\
    &= \mathbb{E}\left[\color{red}{\exp\{AW_t\}\color{blue}{\sigma_t}}\right]\\
    &= \mathbb{E}\left[\exp\{AW_t\}\mathbb{E}[\sigma_t|W_t] \right]   \ \ \ \ \text{(applying (2))}\\
    &= \mathbb{E}[{\exp\{AW_t\}}]\mathbb{E}[\sigma_t]. \tag{3}\\
\end{align}
In the equation (3), I end up with the product of expectations as if $\exp\{AW_t\}$ and $\sigma_t$ were independent. I'm pretty sure (3) is not correct. Maybe for (3) to be true, another assumption is needed, like $\sigma_t$ is a Markovian process? If the separation into a product of expectations is not possible, is there a way to evaluate (1)?

The last line in (3) is incorrect. $E[\sigma_t|W_t]$ is a random variable itself depending on $W_t$, you cannot take it out of the outer expectation and you cannot split the expectation linearly either.
You cannot calculate the value of this expectation without knowing anything how $\sigma_t$ depends on $W_t$. For example, if $\sigma_t \sim \mathcal{N}(W_t,v)$ is Gaussian with mean $W_t$ and variance $v > 0$, then $E[\sigma_t|W_t] = W_t$ and you get the expectation $E[\exp(AW_t)W_t]$. In general, you can use the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality to get an upper bound $(E[\exp(2AW_t)] E[\sigma_t^2])^{1/2}$, but that might not be what you are looking for.
